# How to convert a single character to its hex value?

Tags: text, hexl-mode

I have a character, e.g. `O`, and I want to convert it to its hexadecimal encoded value.
The result must be `4f`.

How can I do this in Emacs 26.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply run M-x `eval-expression` and type `?O`. You will get the following output in the minibuffer:

```
79 (#o117, #x4f, ?O)
```

Comment: `C-x =` (`what-cursor-position`) works as well, it prints something like "Char: O (79, #o117, #x4f) point=146 of 146 (99%) column=0".

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about `?0`. A side note, by default `eval-expression` is bounded to `M-:` which make it much faster...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe no so elegant but should do the trick. Note I have assigned it to "C-." which might be used by other functions in your setup. Reassign as you wish:

```
(defun hexify()
  (interactive)
  (setq hx (format "%x" (char-before)))
  (delete-backward-char 1)
  (insert hx))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-.") 'hexify)
```

Calling the function, *replaces* the character before the cursor with its hex. If you just want the value Arkadiusz's answer will do.